# Spark authentication

Tags: apache-spark, authentication, spark-streaming

Configuration that we are using in our standalone spark cluster version 1.6.0:

```
spark.acls.enable true
spark.admin.acls *
spark.authenticate true
spark.authenticate.secret test123
spark.authentication.BasicFilter.params username=test,password=test456
spark.modify.acls *
spark.ui.filters authentication.BasicFilter
spark.ui.view.acls *
```

When we start our application, the executor tries to fetch the jar from driver http://driver:port/jars/jarname and it's failing with the below error. Could someone please help?

java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we used @ symbol in our password which caused the issue